# Notepad++ : How to find multiple instances of a string on the same line and replace the entire line with found strings

Tags: notepad++, regex, javascript, c++

For example:

```
Suzy sells sea shells for USD$55 and USD$65 and USD$20 
Dave sells all kinds of junk for USD$30
Philip sells CDs for USD$40 and USD$10
```

Output needs to be:

```
55, 65, 20
30
40, 10
```

The Matching string USD appear on a line multiple times.  Is there a way to make this work?

I've tried

```
search: ^.*?USD\$([\d*?]+).*$
replace: $1
```

Doesn't give me ok results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for: `.*?(USD\$(\d+))`

Replace with: `$2,`

Settings as in the screenshot:

[image: settings]

Result:

```
55, 65, 20,  
30, 
40, 10,
```

### Explanation:

```
.*?(USD\$(\d+))
.               #any character
 *              #match previous character between 0-infinity times
  ?             #make previous quantifier non-greedy
   (          ) #capturing group $1
    USD         #literal text
       \$       #literal text, escaped as $ would be a special symbol
         (   )  #capturing group $2
          \d    #match digits, same as [0-9]
            +   #quantifier, match previous symbol between 1-infinity times
```

https://regex101.com/r/IPC6PS/1

Comment: Wow this seems like magic and it works! Thanks so much.

But for my education, how does this know to wrap around and find multiple occurrences of 'USD' and how is it all grouped to $2??

Comment: @user17495 see my recent edit. Also have a look at the regex101 link, it shows pretty good how the regex engine walks over each line and what part matches what text.

Comment: Thanks for taking to the time to explain.

What if I had a longer piece of text like:
"Suzy sells sea shells for USD$55 and USD$65 and USD$20 and other stuff."

then the output becomes
55, 65, 20 and other stuff

is there a way to get rid of "and other stuff" so the output remains the same?

This is where I started with this by matching the whole line till the very end (.*$) but that only found one instance.