# Notepad++ find multiple matches on the same line and only return extracts from those matches

Tags: notepad++, regex

Posting a revision of this question which was initially answered by @mashuptwice (see [Notepad++ : How to find multiple instances of a string on the same line and replace the entire line with found strings](https://superuser.com/q/1732924/399707)).

For example:

```
Suzy sells sea shells for USD$55 and USD$65 and USD$20 
Dave sells all kinds of junk for USD$30 and others
Philip sells CDs for USD$40 and USD$10
```

Output needs to be:

```
55, 65, 20
30
40, 10
```

I've tried

> Search for: .*?(USD$(\d+)) Replace with: $2,

Issue with this is my second line output is

30 and others

I do not want to 'and others' to be matched. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `.*?USD\$(\d+)(?:(?!USD).)*`
- Replace with: `$1,`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
.*?         # 0 or more any character but newline
USD\$       # literally
(\d+)       # group 1, 1 or more digits
(?:         # non capture group
    (?!USD)     # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't USD after
    .           # any character but newline
)*          # end group, may appear 0 or more times
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks so much